# shift alt left click for loop select doesn't work in 2.8 anymore. What did they change now?

Tags: loop, select

The title says it all. This is so incredibly, unbearably annoying.

mesh.loop_select doesn't work now... and I can't figure out that they've made it into. Even when reset to default settings I can no longer loop select... so what's up here?

Comment: 2.8 works with the right mouse button. Alt+Right Click...

Answer (score 6):

In *Edit > Preference > Input* part if you have *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* in this case the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key serves as the third button so the shortcuts do not all work.

Just remove the check mark in the *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* box.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have the "emulate 3 Button mouse" active because the hotkey "alt + mouse click" overlaps with the "loop select".

You can either:

- go to user preferences > input > uncheck emulate 3 button mouse (Duarte solution) or if you need this option active (probably you don't have a 3 button mouse) you can
- (same place) user preferences > input and in the search box from the right, type "loop select" and change the hotkeys to anyone that suits you.

I don't know if in the newest version of Blender this is solved.

Comment: i have "3 button mouse" unselected and it doesn´t work for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean edge loop then it's just alt+right click, I also found out that if your edges aren't truly connected, Blender won't count them as full edge loops. as you said, SUPER annoying. I'll try to help out if I misinterpreted what you meant.

Comment: I'm using alt-left to navigate, since I'm a (former) Maya user. I failed to mention, the loop select seems to work on edges but not on faces for me. Also I can't change the hotkey to anything; it simply won't work at all. I suspected conflicting keys but I've already tried that too. Nothing works.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to try here. I'm usually good at finding what they've changed and adding the appropriate operator. But in this case, I simply can't select a face loop anymore. Not at all, and no clue as to if the operator has changed or not....

Comment: I just went on Blender's Discord channel and confirmed with others that face-loop select is not working with the latest 2.8 build. So I guess I'll just wait and see if they fix it. Cheers!

Comment: Try one more thing, hit ctrl-tab while in edit mode and go to face selection mode, then, alt-right click on between two faces. and apologies for the answer above, it's alt-right click there as well.

Comment: The latest build has fixed the issue. Thanks for the help anyway guys, and taking the time to respond. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In BLender 3.0 they seem to have changed Select Edge Loop to a simple **double click** of left mouse button. (I'm have 3 Button Mouse Emulation enabled).